# Right Align Gap in sIFR

Tags: sifr, alignment

When I right align there is what appears to be like a 3-5 pixel padding on the right. But when it is left aligned it is perfectly lined up with the content. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a negative value for `tuneWidth` to remove the extra space.